# Django jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am currently facing a situation can a complicated and I will take the time to explain as clearly as possible my problem.

I use django v1.8

I have a view that shows me a list of results , and the template dedicated to this view, I added ajax method to quickly filter the current results .
Everything works fine , but only when the page is refreshed manually the ajax is cleared , I know it's normal, I would I like to do is to change the URL of the browser.

my file.js:

```
$(function(){
    $('#filter').change(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/find/object/filter/",
                        data: {
                                'preference': $('#preference').val(),
                                'city': $('#hsearch').val(),
                                'spec': $('#mplspecialite').val(),
                                'mplace': $('#mplace').val(),
                                'filter': $('#filter').val(),
                                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                        },
                        success: searchResult,
                        dataType: 'html'
                });
    });
});

function searchResult(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#dynamic-results').html(data);
}
```

Ajax view.py:

```
def ajax_something_search(request):
    args = {}

    if request.method != "POST":
        raise Http404(request.method, _("Not allow method !"))

    # code
    # code
    # code
    val_url = urllib.parse.urlencode(args)
    url = reverse(
        'manage-core:core-search') + '?' + val_url
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

My search `view.py` (I redirect all my ajax param send in this view):

```
def search_something(request):
    args = {}
    # code
    # code
    # code
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'city' in request.GET or 'partner' in request.GET\
                or 'filter' in request.GET:
            q_city = request.GET.get('city', False)
            q_preference = request.GET.get('preference', False)
            q_speciality = request.GET.get('speciality', False)
            q_partner_name = request.GET.get('partner', False)
            q_filter = request.GET.get('filter', False)
            args['results'] = args['ctx']
            if q_city:
                args['results'] = args['results'].filter(
                    city__name__icontains=q_city)
            if q_preference:
                args['results'] = args['results'].filter(service=q_preference)

            if q_partner_name:
                args['results'] = args['results'].filter(
                    name__icontains=q_partner_name)

            if q_filter:
                if q_filter == '1':
                    args['results'] = args['results'].order_by('min_to_order')
                elif q_filter == '2':
                    args['results'] = args['results'].order_by('mark')
                elif q_filter == '3':
                    args['results'] = args['results'].order_by('remarq')
                elif q_filter == '4':
                    args['results'] = args['results'].order_by('name')
            if args['results'].count() > 1:
                args['filterform'] = SearchFilterForm()
            del args['ctx']

            template_name = 'something/snippets/'\
                'ajax_object_search.html'
            return render_to_response(
                template_name,
                args,
                context_instance=RequestContext(request)
            )
```

How can i update the browser url when ajax called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser URL can be changed programmatically by editing the history entry using `history.replaceState`. It's virtually identical to `history.pushState` except that `pushState` adds a browser history entry and `replaceState` modifies the current one. I'll continue with `pushState`.

As a word of caution, you will be opening yourself up to more complexity if this is not absolutely needed. This is because you'll have to implement the behaviour to modify the page should somebody navigate backwards in history.

`history` is under the DOM `window` object.

```
history.pushState(someState, "some title", "page.html");
```

`someState` is an object that is associated to that browser history entry. 
e.g. `{ city: "London", lon: 51.5072, lat: 0.1275 }`

The first param (`someState`) is subsequently provided when the `popstate` event is fired on history change. Another warning, when the browser is reloaded you shouldn't rely on the `popstate` event as it **may or may not** be fired depending on the browser. Grab the state object  from `history.state` instead as it's there without relying on the event being fired.

The middle param can be the empty string or a string of your choice, it's ignored by browsers for now.

The last param is the URL you want to push into the browser history, it can be absolute or relative. It won't be loaded by the browser.

**More Specifically**:
You could use `pushState` in the success callback of your AJAX request which pushes the data sent in the request into a history entry. When the user navigates back or reloads the page, this data can be pulled back and used to send the AJAX request again.

If you anticipate that you'll be doing more of this, you might want to look into in browser routing libraries.

Good luck!

You can read more about [HTML5PushState here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

**EDIT:** Response to the comment.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$(function(){
  $('#filter').change(function() {

    var relQuery = null;

    // The stuff you send in your request
    var reqData = {
      'preference': $('#preference').val(),
      'city': $('#hsearch').val(),
      'spec': $('#mplspecialite').val(),
      'mplace': $('#mplace').val(),
      'filter': $('#filter').val(),
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
    };

    // Make the query string that you need. 
    // Probably looks like some variant of this.
    // Look at jQuery.param docs.
    relQuery = "?" + $.param( reqData );

    // The request
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/find/object/filter/",
      data: reqData,
      success: searchResult,
      dataType: 'html'
    });

    // Change the current history entry to have that
    // URL query string.
    history.replaceState( {}, '',  relQuery);

  });
});

function searchResult(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#dynamic-results').html(data);

}
```

Comment: Minn, Thank ! But look ! When user select filter with html select tag ajax filter the context result page all work correctly! but when he refresh page with F5 or other the ajax filter disappear that's my issue ! I want to update the url browser with the given of firebug console log(firebug show me the correct url i want to replace) if this url change user can refresh page ! How can do that ?

Comment: Create an object that represents the state of your filter and push a new history entry with that state. On page load you should check for the history state associated with that entry. If it exists, use the contents of that object to re-apply the filter.

Comment: Hum ! Maybe i understand you! look (last time please i want to solve my issue)! When user make a search that's url show on browser (http://localhost:8000/search/object/) ok ! now when user check the select html tag in this page all work ! firebug show me that url i want to replace to(GET:http://localhost:8000/search/object/?filter_name=value&filter_name=value/)<<<--- that's is the url i want to get in the browser after ajax event call !

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you want now. More simply, in the success callback for the AJAX request, use `history.replaceState({}, "", queryParam)` where `queryParam` is your relative URL string which looks like this `?filter_name=value&filter_name=value`.

Comment: Ok ! look my file.js in my posted question ! How can i do that with it ? Where is QueryParam, where can i take history ? Can you adapt it with my file.js Please my friend !

Comment: You'll need to define what actually goes in the query string. This is an example using your JS, too long to post in the comment. I've added it into the answer.

Comment: OOOOOH yes ! yes ! yes! I have not try but i kwnow it work ! Thanks Minn !